# Resolve JavaScript variable inside Jsp function calling

Tags: javascript, struts2

```
<button value="Cancel" class="commonBtn commonBtn-small cancelBtn "
                    onclick="cancelEvent(<script>document.write(cancelButtonAction);</script>);" tabindex="11" type="button"><script>document.write(cancelButtonAction);</script></button>
```

1) `<script>document.write(cancelButtonAction);</script>` this is fine work and resolve the value but

2)`onclick="cancelEvent(<script>document.write(cancelButtonAction);</script>);"`  this is not working single and double quotes also apply on it but still not working.

any one can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="write(cancelButtonAction)"
```

I believe this should work..

Comment: @Aghnesh if it works, you should accept the answer by marking the white V in top left corner of it

Comment: @Rajesh Your believe doesn't help future readers until you explain what did you do and why it should work.